# bridgeless graph

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that every graph containing only even vertices is bridgeless.

I understand that an even vertex is one with an even degree.  Therefore an even vertex is one which is connected to an even number of vertices.

I also understand an edge $e = uv$ in a connected graph G whose removal creates a disconnected graph is a bridge.

I don't know how to use this to do the proof 
:(

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $e=uv$ is a bridge. When you remove $e$, you reduce the degrees of $u$ and $v$ by $1$ each, so if they were even to begin with, they’re odd in the disconnected graph $G-e$. Let $G_u$ be the component of $G-e$ that contains $u$. Get a contradiction by showing that the sum of the degrees of the vertices of $G_u$ is odd.

Comment: @BrianMScott in $G_u$ every vertex would have an even degree except for $u$ which will have an odd degree.  This results in an odd degree sum which is a contradiction.  Therefore the graph does not have any bridges.  IE there is no edge we can remove which will create a disconnected graph.  Is this fine?

Comment: @sarah: That’s exactly right.